# d3.js: Text too sharp

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently working on using D3 for Data Visualization, so far, I am able to create a nested donut chart. Now, I am trying to add a text in the middle. So far so good, however, when it renders, the text is too 'sharp'.

Please see image below.

[image]

I have tried using `shape-rendering: crispEdges` but it is not working.

Here is the script for the text:

```
g.append("text")
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.style("font-family", "AgfaRotisSansSerif")
.style("font-weight", "100")
.style("font-size", "2em")
.style("fill", "#8e44ad")
.text("REQUESTS");
```

CSS wise, I do not have any.

Comment: What do you mean by "sharp"?

Comment: @bjskistad, by sharp, I meant, the lines are too jagged. It is not smooth at all.

Comment: The appropriate CSS property is [text-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-rendering), not `shape-rendering`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when you draw the same text over and over again at the same point. Check using the browser dom inspector to see how many text elements you have in the centre of the pie. If it's more than one and they're of the same string, that's your problem.

See the effect here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/2059/

```
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var dataSet = [{x: 0, text: "No Overplot"}, {x: 1, text: "Overplot", }, {x: 1, text: "Overplot", }, {x: 1, text: "Overplot", }, {x: 1, text: "Overplot", }, {x: 1, text: "Overplot", }, {x: 1, text: "Overplot", }];

var circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr({
        x:function(d, i){ return d.x * 100 + 60 },
        y:50,
        fill: 'black',
        stroke: 'none',
    })
    .text (function(d) { return d.text; })
```

Comment: Thank you! Upon inspection of the elements, I have found out that the 'REQUESTS' text has been written as many times depending on how many arcs were created. So, instead of appending the text to the chart, I appended it into the main svg.

Comment: I thought i'd add an additional example of where this might happen: i had it occur in plot titles and y-labels, the reason being when i did a data join i did it on .data(y_label) instead of .data([y_label])